# Valgrind: Losing bytes after assigning one pointer to another

Tags: c++, pointers

I am writing a List class. When I run the program through valgrind, I get the following errors:

```
==26620== 
==26620== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26620==     in use at exit: 160 bytes in 10 blocks
==26620==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 4 frees, 82,632 bytes allocated
==26620== 
==26620== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 3
==26620==    at 0x4C2B1EC: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26620==    by 0x10EC98: List<int>::ListNode::addNext(int) (List.h:20)
==26620==    by 0x10E9AB: List<int>::insert(int) (List.cpp:28)
==26620==    by 0x10BA07: main (main.cpp:62)
==26620== 
==26620== 144 (16 direct, 128 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==26620==    at 0x4C2B1EC: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26620==    by 0x10E93D: List<int>::insert(int) (List.cpp:18)
==26620==    by 0x10BA07: main (main.cpp:62)
==26620== 
==26620== LEAK SUMMARY:
==26620==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==26620==    indirectly lost: 128 bytes in 8 blocks
==26620==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26620==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26620==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26620== 
==26620== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==26620== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

As requested:

List.h

```
#ifndef CDR_LIST_H
#define CDR_LIST_H

template <typename T>
class List {
private:
class ListNode {
private:
    T entry;
    ListNode *next;
public:
    ListNode(T entry) : entry(entry), next(nullptr) {}
    ~ListNode() {
        if (next != nullptr) {
            delete next;
        }
    }

    void addNext(T entry) {
        this->next = new ListNode(entry); // Here
        setNext(next);
    }

    void setNext(ListNode *next) {
        this->next = next;
    }

    ListNode *getNext() {
        return this->next;
    }

    T getEntry() { return this->entry; }
};

ListNode *root;
int size;
public:
List();
~List();

void deleteList(ListNode *root);

void insert(T entry);

T at(int index);

void deleteAt(int index);

void printList();
};
#endif //CDR_LIST_H
```

List.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"

template <typename T>
List<T>::List() : size(0) {
this->root = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
List<T>::~List() {
deleteList(this->root);
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::insert(T entry) {
if (this->size == 0 || this->root == nullptr) {
    root = new ListNode(entry); // And here
    size++;
    return;
}
ListNode *currNode = this->root;
while (currNode->getNext() != nullptr) {
    currNode = currNode->getNext();
}
currNode->addNext(entry);
this->size++;
}

template <typename T>
T List<T>::at(int index) {
if (index >= this->size) {
    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of list range");
}

ListNode *currNode = this->root;
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    currNode = currNode->getNext();
}

return currNode->getEntry();
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::deleteList(ListNode *root) {
if (root == nullptr) {
    delete root;
    return;
}

deleteList(root->getNext());
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::deleteAt(int index) {
if (index >= this->size) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Index out of range");
}

ListNode *currNode = this->root;
ListNode *parentNode = this->root;
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    parentNode = currNode;
    currNode = currNode->getNext();
}

parentNode->setNext(currNode->getNext());
// delete currNode;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::printList() {
ListNode *currNode = this->root;
while (currNode != nullptr) {
    std::cout << currNode->getEntry() << std::endl;
    currNode = currNode->getNext();
}
}




template class List<int>;
```

I understand that I'm creating a pointer is both cases, but since I need the data it is pointing to, I can't delete them. So, how are these cases considered byte losses and how can I avoid it?

Thanks

Comment: Post more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void addNext(T entry) {
        this->next = new ListNode(entry); // Here
        setNext(next); // this line is unnecessary
}
```

The marked line actually overwrites this->next with the same value. While it doesn't change the actual value, Valgrind might warn you of a memory leak.